# External API compatibility with Custom connectors

Tags: powerapp, oauth, custom-connector, power-platform

We want to build a custom connector inside Power Apps which integrate with external API. and for this integration we will use the Oauth2.0. Now the external API provides these details for the Authentication:-

```
Token name - ********************

Grant Type - Authorization Code (With PKCE)

Callback Url - https://first.localhost:9000/auth

Auth Url - https://auth.********.net/oauth2/authorize

Access Token Url - https://auth.********.net/oauth2/token

Client Id - *****

Code Challenge Method - SHA-256
```

so is this info enough/sufficient to configure the custom connector's OAuth2.0, as on the custom connector we will be asked to provide these info:-

[image]

so what is the missing info in the external API that we need to get and ask the vendor about them?

Thanks

**EDIT** now i checked with external API vendor, and they showed me how they authenticate using Postman, where seems there are 2 steps:-

1. They provide the clientID, clientSecret, AuthorizationURL & AccessTokenURL
2. After that they get an access token >> and they submit it as an header to the Request, as follow:-

[image]

so is this type of OAuth 2.0 supported by custom connectors?

Comment: Does your external API use implicit grant or client credentials grant flow to provide authorisation tokens?

Comment: @CallumCrowley client credentials as we need to enter a username/password later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit Grant and Client Credentials Grant flows cannot be used to authenticate Custom Connectors.

"Note that only Authorization Code Grant flows and On-Behalf-Of flows support refresh tokens (see this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/blogs/30daysmsgraph-day-12-authentication-and-authorization-scenarios/) for more information). Implicit Grants and Client Credentials Grants do not suport refresh tokens, so may not be used to authenticate Custom Connectors."

[Verifying OAUTH configuration for Custom Connectors](https://support.microsoft.com/topic/verifying-oauth-configuration-for-custom-connectors-ceadbd1d-5a44-5615-208b-029f7ffe6107)

This is why you need to provide a client secret for example.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i did not notice it.. now i am not sure what is the exact meaning of implicit grant,,, but can you check my edit , to see how we authenticate the external API using Postman and if  this is supported by custom connectors?

Comment: I would check with your API provider, as to whether they are using Implicit Grant or Client Credential Grant flows for their API. If so, it isn't possible to use the API to authenticate with custom connectors.

Comment: ok thanks,, so from the way they authenticate inside Postman, can it gives us the answer if they use   Implicit Grant or Client Credential Grant? thanks

Comment: Yes, it appears they are using Client Credential Grant flow. More information: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/client-credentials-flow

Comment: ok so in this case how i can authenticate the custom connector in the same way? first by generating the access_token and secondly submitting the access_token as part of the header? is this supported inside custom connectors?

Comment: As already stated above, APIs that use a Client Credential Flow cannot be authenticated in custom connectors

Comment: ok i see. so can we call this type of APIs using Power Automate ? like sending an http request?

Comment: Yes, you could use multiple HTTP calls in Power Automate to utilise the API

Comment: is there some tutorials on how to implement Client Credential Flow in power automate? thanks a lot for your very helpful replies

Comment: I'm not aware of any but sure Google will have some help.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same questions months ago, and i found that the article of [Wael Kdouh](https://waelkdouh.medium.com/how-to-connect-a-custom-power-apps-connector-to-azure-api-management-bc3efb433ae4) is very useful and detailed.

You will find all the required details you need in order to build your custom connector properly.

Cordially.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already read the article,, but my question is about the missing info from our external API? not sure if it contains all the necessary info or not? for example inside our  external API there is not any info about ClientSecret,, so can we replace it with any other info we have?

Comment: Okay, you need to share with us your API documentation, i mean all the fields you have on your API Structure

Comment: i already shared them in my question

Comment: can you please check my edit to the original question?